# Pylint and mypy opinion clash on iheriting from static methods

Tags: python, pylint, mypy

In our project, we are using mypy for type checking and pylint for code quality assessment. I bumped into a problem with the combination of these tools in non-static inheritance of static methods and I would like to know whether there is a better way of writing the following.

In my case, I have an abstract class with a method which is supposed to be overridden, but has a state-less default implementation:

```
class Base:
    def hello(self, arg: int) -> int:
        return arg + 5

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, inc: int) -> None:
        self.inc = inc

    def hello(self, arg: int) -> int:
        return arg + self.inc
```

In the previous example, pylint complains about the `Base.hello` method that could've been a function (because it does not use `self`)

Python allows me to annotate the `Base.hello` method as static as follows:

```
class Base:
    @staticmethod
    def hello(arg: int) -> int:
        return arg + 5
```

This fixes the pylint `no-self-use` warning but triggers the mypy warning `Signature of "hello" incompatible with supertype "Base"`

The obvious solution that I use now is placing a `#pylint: disable=no-self-use` directive before the `Base.hello` definition, but I would like to know if there's another, perhaps more direct way to achieve the same behavior without any pylint or mypy warnings.